# How to detect shape resizing in word document

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

Is there a way to detect shape resizing in word document?

Regards

Comment: I cant find any way to try, I am asking for any idea to try

Answer (score 2):

There are no events in the [Word Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events.aspx) provides this. But you can save shape's size, then handle for example [DocumentBeforeSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.documentbeforesave.aspx), and then:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in wordDoc.Shapes)
{ 
   if (shape.Width != oldShapeWidth || shape.Height != oldShapeHeight)
   {
   //...
   }
}
```